# How can I prove that if the relation R is a subset of the relation S, then the inverse of R is a subset of the inverse of S?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

Let $R$ and $S$ be relations from $A$ to $B$. Prove that $(R \subseteq S) \Rightarrow (R^{-1} \subseteq S^{-1})$

This is what I have written up thus far:

**Theorem.** $(R \subseteq S) \Rightarrow (R^{-1} \subseteq S^{-1})$

*Proof.* By direct proof. We assume $R \subseteq S$ is true.

Given that $R$ and $S$ are relations from $A$ to $B$ we know:

$$R \subseteq A \times B$$
$$S \subseteq A \times B$$

Then, $\forall x, y ((x, y) \in R \Rightarrow (x, y) \in A \times B)$

Likewise, $\forall x, y ((x, y) \in S \Rightarrow (x, y) \in A \times B)$

We know $(x, y) \in R \iff (y, x) \in R^{-1}$

It follows that:

$$\forall x, y \thinspace ((y, x) \in R^{-1} \Rightarrow (y, x) \in B \times A)$$

$$\forall x, y \thinspace ((y, x) \in S^{-1} \Rightarrow (y, x) \in B \times A)$$

Thus, $(y, x) \in R^{-1} \Rightarrow (x, y) \in R \Rightarrow (x, y) \in S \Rightarrow (y, x) \in S^{-1}$

Therefore, $(R \subseteq S) \Rightarrow (R^{-1} \subseteq S^{-1})$

**Q.E.D.**

---

I attempted to use all the definitions I know about subsets and relations in order to write up this proof. However, I am not sure if I my proof is correct, or (provided that this proof isn't entirely wrong) that my logic is sound.

Comment: Looks good!  One technicality: you said $(y,x) \in A \times B$ .. That should be $B \times A$

Comment: @Bram28 Ah! Sorry about that. That was a typo. I wrote this up on paper first and typed it up wrong. I will fix it right now.

Comment: OK, looks fine now.  Note that you never really use the A and B in the proof ... and indeed you don't need them. Just say that this workd for any $ x$ and $y$

Comment: @Bram28 I can sort of see that now, but I am new to proof writing, and I prefer to write everything since I lack the mathematical maturity to figure out these proofs without unraveling all the definitions first.

I have a question, I sort of made a leap of faith with that last line by following a somewhat similar proof in my textbook. Could you please explain to me why I can just say $(y, x) \in R^{-1} \Rightarrow (x, y) \in R \Rightarrow (x, y) \in S \Rightarrow (y, x) \in S^{-1}$ ? Writing out the subset of $A \times B$ stuff helped me see it, but it still seems a bit off to me.

Comment: That is an excellent habit to have! And you did nothing wrong :)

Comment: Well, you have to refer to A and B in so far as that when you are told that $R$ and $S$ are relations from $A$ to $B$, you know that they are two-place relations (and hence all elements are of the form (x,y) ...and an inverse actually exists ...). But there is no need to point out that $(x,y) \in A \times B \Rightarrow (y,x) \in B \times A$.

Comment: @Cherry_Developer In which textbook did you see the proof you comment?